# Videochat implementation for Nativescript

Tags: javascript, nativescript, videochat

Can anyone please guide me how can I implement videochat within a nativescript application?. I have been looking around and I don't find a way to do it.

Comment: There are many Android and iOS SDKs on the interwebz for achieving just that. What you want to do in NativeScript is just call to their API through JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not at the point where I could make it work natively, so I would fall back on using a web-view.  This would also help to setup the sockets and handshakes needed for two way live chats, like webRTC.